Does the Navigate "to" support second level forwarding?
Here is my app.jsx
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import OTAndTOGateKeeper from "./components/otAndTO/OTAndTOGateKeeper.jsx";
import LoginForm from "./components/otAndTO/LoginForm.jsx";
 return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/otAndTO' element={<OTAndTOGateKeeper/>}>
          <Route index element={<OTAndTOForm/>}/>
          <Route path="login" element={<LoginForm/>}/>
        </Route>        
      </Routes>
    </Router>
);

Here is my OTAndTOGateKeeper.jsx
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import OTAndTOForm from "./OTAndTOForm.jsx";
export default function OTAndTOGateKeeper(){
    let finalComponent;
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken")){
        finalComponent=<OTAndTOForm/>
    } else {
        finalComponent=<Navigate to="/otAndTO/login"/>
    }
    return finalComponent;
}

When I Browse the '/otAndTO', it should return the login form; unfortunately, there are nothing return.
However, when I change the App.jsx and OTAndTOGateKeeper.jsx as the following:
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import OTAndTOGateKeeper from "./components/otAndTO/OTAndTOGateKeeper.jsx";
import LoginForm from "./components/otAndTO/LoginForm.jsx";
 return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/otAndTO' element={<OTAndTOGateKeeper/>}>
          <Route index element={<OTAndTOForm/>}/>
        </Route>
        <Route path="login" element={<LoginForm/>}/>            
      </Routes>
    </Router>
);

import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import OTAndTOForm from "./OTAndTOForm.jsx";
export default function OTAndTOGateKeeper(){
    let finalComponent;
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken")){
        finalComponent=<OTAndTOForm/>
    } else {
        finalComponent=<Navigate to="/login"/>
    }
    return finalComponent;
}

It works as expected.
Here is my environment:
"react-dom": "^18.3.1",
"react": "^18.3.1",
"react-router-dom": "^7.0.2"

I am using the vite+react development tools.
Is the  only work for the top level URL?


Does the Navigate "to" support second level forwarding?

Yes, it will navigate to whatever path you specify.
OTAndTOGateKeeper is a layout route component, so it must render an Outlet component for the nested routes to render their element content into. It also can't return a redirect to a route it is wrapping (because this replaces the Outlet and then nothing is rendered!).
OTAndTOForm will be rendered on the /otAndTO index route, so OTAndTOGateKeeper should not also be trying to render it.
Update OTAndTOGateKeeper to the following:
import { Navigate, Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import OTAndTOForm from "./OTAndTOForm.jsx";

export default function OTAndTOGateKeeper() {
  return sessionStorage.getItem("accessToken")
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/otAndTO/login" replace />;
}

Rearrange the routes so that both the OTAndTOForm index route and the LoginForm login route are rendered under the parent "/otAndTO" route, and render OTAndTOGateKeeper as protected layout route only around the OTAndTOForm route.
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/otAndTO">
      <Route element={<OTAndTOGateKeeper />}>
        <Route index element={<OTAndTOForm />} />    {/* "/otAndTO" */}
      </Route>
      <Route path="login" element={<LoginForm />} /> {/* "/otAndTO/login" */}
    </Route>      
  </Routes>
</Router>

